# How to Display .Gif image in image view Android

Tags: android, image, zooming, gif

How to display .gif image in image view?

And how to .gif image zoom in and zoom out in Android?

Comment: Did you try working on the problem? If so please post your code.

Comment: See if this helps you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494413/play-downloaded-gif-image-in-android

Comment: Punctuation, capitalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [GifImageView](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView) library for displaying  gif images from https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView

Comment: Thanks.. But zoom in and zoom out problem

Comment: @ParthKathiriya GifImageView extends ImageView. so normal zoom can be done in that.

Comment: @ParthKathiriya for more info how to zoom follow http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

Answer (score 0):

Library for playing gifs on Android Kotlin. Simple android view to display gifs efficiently. You can start, pause and stop gifView. Example usages can be found in example project.

Usage
Step 1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

Step 2. Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.harunkor:AndroidGifViewPlayerKotlin:1.0.0'
    }
```

Layout :

```
<tr.com.harunkor.gifviewplayer.GifMovieView
        android:id="@+id/gifViewPlayer"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"/>
```

Code :

```
    //gif player layout variable.
        var gifViewPlayer: GifMovieView?  = findViewById(R.id.gifViewPlayer) as GifMovieView 
//gif animation file set  in drawable folder. 
            gifViewPlayer!!.setMovieResource(R.drawable.carkifelek)
//gif animation Movie callback and set 
            gifViewPlayer?.setMovie(gifViewPlayer?.getMovie()!!);
// gif animation hide. 
            gifViewPlayer?.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
    // gif animation  visible  
            gifViewPlayer?.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// gif animation file set  in assets folder. 
            gifViewPlayer?.setMovieAssets("eat.gif");
        var path:String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/danc.gif";   
// gif animation file set in Android device. 
            gifViewPlayer?.setMovieFile(path);
// gif animation (URL stream) show link.  
            gifViewPlayer?.setMovieUrl("https://scdn.androidcommunity.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/androidify2.gif");
// gif animation pause
            gifViewPlayer?.setPaused(true);  
    // gif animation play 
            gifViewPlayer?.setPaused(false);
```

Manifest
Permission : (dependent on use)

Necessary :

WARNING! : compile sdk version should be 28.